# WYSIWYG editor with file and image upload

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm looking for good WYSIWYG editor, which can handle image and file uploads as well as some basic markup. I tried CKEditor - it looks alright but it's quite heavy, nicEditor - lightweight, fast, has decent image uploading but has no filemanager. What would you recommend?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll CKEditor and TinyMCE are I believe the leading online richtext editors.

If you don't have to limit yourself to web apps you should check out [Windows Live Writer](http://download.live.com/writer). If you have OSX you should look into [iWeb](http://www.apple.com/uk/ilife/iweb/) as its the easiest and most intuitive WYSIWYG html editor that I find most enjoyable to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another good one would be [Froala Editor](http://editor.froala.com). It has image upload and resize that works even on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

We use TinyMCE. It has plenty of plugins which can solve pretty much every need.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [telerik](http://www.telerik.com) editor. It's not cheap, but it is very nice.